# Is it possible to turn "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" into a Fatal Error?

Tags: php, error-handling

If a variable is holding `NULL` in PHP, attempting to access a property on it results in the notice "Trying to get property of non-object". If an attempt is made to call a method on it, however, the result is "Fatal error: Call to a member function *method-name*() on a non-object":

```
<?php
$obj = NULL;
var_dump($obj->prop);
$obj->method();
```

http://codepad.org/HZyYd12A

Is there a way to make PHP treat **both** of these runtime errors as Fatal Errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your own error handler, which can promote this kind of error to a fatal error.
See http://php.net/set_error_handler and specifically the examples.

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an idea but i think you can handle it manualy by catching the notice and throwing an exception followed by the line

exit();

;)

Comment: Please expand on how you would catch a notice. :)

Comment: I'm writing from a mobile so I didn't expand :D sorry