# Make "undefined constant, assumed literal" fatal

Tags: php

Is it possible to disable this *feature* of php, when it interprets unquoted strings as strings, without adding any code to the program? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751246/is-it-possible-to-turn-notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-into-a-fat), but the project I am currently working on has already got a lot of complex error handling, so I don't want to mess with that. I am hoping that maybe this can be done via php.ini now, or maybe there's a way to define a handler only for a specific notice. So, is it possible?